# Not able to render what i have in the Shading window

Tags: rendering, shaders

I'm new on Blender and to practice a little bit on it i am doing the Donut tutorial from Blender Guru. At one point during the tutorial i'm able to see in the Shading window of Blender the Sprinkles on the Dunut like you can see in the following picture:

[image]

If i try to render my Donut using the short key F12 i get the following result:

[image]

You can see that i don't have the sprinkles on the Donut. Could anyone give me an hint on how to solve this problem ?
Thanks.
Luca

Comment: are your sprinkles hidden for the render in the outliner?

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer. My sprinkles are not hidden for the render in the outliner, like you can see in this picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7b06.png